# OpenAPI Issue - Bad Mapping

Tags: c#, rest, visual-studio-2019, openapi-generator

I'm using OpenAPI through Visual Studio 2019 in order to map to my client classes and method of my API Rest, however it works ina strange way:

1. DateTime types are converted in DateTimeOffset
2. double types are converted in decimal types
3. Nullable enums are converted as not nullable

It's very strange behavior and I'm not idea the reason why.
Is there some way in order to achieve a correct mapping of my types client side?