# OpenAPI Issue - Bad Mapping - VS2022

Tags: c#, openapi, code-generation

I'm having same issue in visual studio 2022 than this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71702792/openapi-issue-bad-mapping/). Specifically with Date types.
I'm creating a new question here since mine has been deleted from the previous post because my question, which is exactly the same question than the previous one, target VS2022 instead of VS2019...

The used extension is **Unchase OpenApi**.

I know how I can choose between DateTime or DateTimeOffset, but I don't want to have to choose between only one of those since we use both Date types.

How can we make it to just respect the types we have defined without having to choose between one or the other ?

And, if we don't choose none of this types (to let him guess alone) then, I'll end up with no types which can't be even compiled.

I'm not able to find any information over the whole internet, and even this question has no answer yet...

Thanks for helping.

I tried to not choose any Date type, in order to let him respect what we have declared, but I ended up with no type at all and this can't even be compiled...